# VBA concatenate Date and text

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate column B and C, in to column O.

The code i have is this.  The code is giving a value amount rather than date.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub ConcatJEcomment()

  Dim LastRow As Long
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("O2:O" & LastRow) = Evaluate(Replace("B2:B#&"" - ""&C2:C#", "#", LastRow))
  'You want to pull date and Type -- in this order
  'Range = where do you want this to be put

End Sub
```

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TEXT & ARRAY

### A One-Liner? Nope!

The **Excel formula**

```
=TEXT(B2,"MM/DD/YYYY")&" - "&C2
```

works just fine.

I was surprised that the initial **VBA formula**

```
Range("O2:O" & LastRow) = Evaluate(Replace("B2:B#&"" - ""&C2:C#", "#", LastRow))
```

would even work. So following its logic I concluded:

```
Range("O2:O" & LastRow) = Evaluate( _
    Replace("TEXT(B2:B#,""MM/DD/YYYY"")&"" - ""&C2:C#", "#", LastRow))
```

It doesn't work, looks like the **TEXT** function doesn't like arrays. The result is always the concatenated values from the **second** row (first row of data).

### A Solution

You can always loop through the range:

```
Sub ConcatJEcomment()

  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim lngRow As Long ' Row Counter
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  For lngRow = 2 To LastRow
    Range("O" & lngRow) = Range("B" & lngRow).Text _
        & " - " & Range("C" & lngRow).Text
  Next

End Sub
```

### Another Issue

Since my system uses '**.**' instead of '**/**' as date separator, I wanted to show the result with slashes:

```
    Range("O" & lngRow) = Format(Range("B" & lngRow), "MM/DD/YYYY") _
        & " - " & Range("C" & lngRow).Text
```

The Excel formula did this without problems but here **It doesn't work**. No slashes!?

A workaround would be:

```
    Range("O" & lngRow) = Replace(Format(Range("B" & lngRow), "MM/DD/YYYY"), _
        ".", "/") & " - " & Range("C" & lngRow).Text
```

I hope someone figures out a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Range("O2:O" & LastRow) = Format(Cells(LastRow, 2).Value,"mm/dd/yyyy") & " - " & Cells(LastRow,3)`